# Passing a list in c++ as reference

Tags: c++, list, pass-by-reference

I want to be able to modify a list and print it in the `main()` function. But I am unable to compile the code. The error is when I am calling `myFunction()`.

Also, how do I access the list within the function? Does `*it1` correctly store the string in this case? Or should I have a list like `list<String *> temp`? I want to be able to access all the elements of the list and print it out.

```
int main(){
    list<String> *temp = new list<String>;
    myFunction(temp);//calling the function ----this is erroring
    //print the elements of the list..I need not pass the pointer, since I just want to print the list? and not edit it?
    printList(temp);
}

void printList(list<String> &temp){
    std::list<String>::iterator it1 = temp.begin();

    for (; it1 != temp.end(); ++it1)
    {
        printf("\n %s \n", *it1);
        //is *it1 expected to print the string in this list of strings?
    }
}

void myFunction(list<String> &temp){
    temp.push_back("Data_1");
    temp.push_back("Data_2");
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Does the program not work? Please be specific, and make a [mre]

Comment: Yes, my program doesn't work. I am unable to compile.

Comment: That's not how you call a function; you must not specify the type of the parameters a second time when you call it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, have fixed it,

Comment: Then add the exact error message to the question.

Comment: Should just be `myFunction(*temp);`.  Also note that you need to declare `myFunction` above `main`.

Comment: It is rarely (if ever) needed to create a `std::list` dynamically using a pointer. Most likely you can just use `list<String> temp; myFunction(temp);` and forget about pointers and `new`.

Comment: will I be able to edit the list in that case? @Galik

Comment: @ccoding Yes of course. As long as you pass it to a function that accepts it by reference (like your function already does).

Comment: Yes, but now I need to pass the list which was modified to another function to just print it. I don't want to print in the same function,...Can you help me with that..

Comment: @ccoding If you only want to print the `std::list` without modifying it then you should pass it by *const reference* as `void printList(const std::list<String>& temp);` but what you already have will work too.

Comment: Is the way I am using the iterator correct?

Comment: @ccoding the iterator, yes. But not the `printf`, no. `%s` expects a `char*`, not a `String`

Answer (score 4):

1. When passing an object by reference in C++, you specify the object itself, not a pointer to it.  Here, you want to pass the list which `temp` points to, which is `*temp`.
2. Functions in C++ have to be declared before they are used.

Try:

```
void myFunction(list<String> &);

int main(){
  list<String> *temp = new list<String>;
  myFunction(*temp);
  //print the elements of the list
}

void myFunction(list<String> &temp){
  temp.push_back("Data_1");
  temp.push_back("Data_2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is declared to take a `list<String>&` reference, but you are passing it a `list<String>*` pointer instead.  So either:

- get rid of the pointer (you don't need it anyway):

```cpp
int main(){
    list<String> temp;
    myFunction(temp);
    //print the elements of the list
}
```

- dereference the pointer:

```cpp
int main(){
    list<String> *temp = new list<String>;
    myFunction(*temp);
    //print the elements of the list
    delete temp;
}
```

Comment: In the first case, will it populate the temp list? Agreed on the second part,..

Comment: @ccoding yes, it will

Answer (score 1):

First,the declarition of myFunction should before the main,because the compiler dont know the function.
Then,the function argument is a reference,but you pass a pointer to it, inappropriate.

Comment: Also, how do I iterate through this list..in the function "MyFunction".Have updated the question for the same